# Filter Nominatim data by Class or Type

Tags: postgresql, nominatim

Is it possible to prevent certain results based on "class" and/or "types"?  For example, I do not want any results that have the following class or types:

class: natural, highway
type: peak, footway, tertiary

Currently the results for this query includes MANY "motorways".  I only want places (houses, cities) to be returned:

```
q=1505+North+S&addressdetails=1&exclude_place_ids=206651397%2C232991588%2C69754855&countrycodes=us&viewbox=-105.5274544234%2C39.774601254671%2C-105.0274544234%2C40.274601254671&accept-language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9
```

My other options include: 1)removing the data from the Nominatim database. 2)  removing results from the resultset after the query has executed.  I don't love either of these other options - but willing to experiment!

Comment: I've filtered by city, state, country and homestead using the "featuretype" parameter.  But these don't provide the filtering I need.  Just trying to only get back certain "types" and/or "classes" that I specify.  I also found references to adding bracketed values in the q= query string, but again - this just seems to select certain items (ie: [hospital] ) and doesn't exclude items.  I'm willing to adjust the nominatim engine search.php file - it doesn't only have to be at the query level.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Will you please add your clarifications to your question?  There is an edit button at the bottom of your question.  I also suggest adding the query that you are using, or at least a sample.  It makes it much easier for people to give you an answer.

Comment: I updated for you (and others).  Hopefully someone out there is experienced enough to solve.

Comment: here is the API reference for Nominatim http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search/  You may be able to filter by class

Comment: jbalk...are you just answering to answer?  if you aren't technical...and you don't have useful "stack exchange" quality answers - you're simply wasting everyone's time.   "What have you tried...?"  and "Here's the documentation" - are strong indicators that you don't have the chops to be here as a resource.

Comment: I was trying to pry important details about your question from you so others who know about this specific topic can help you. I am technical, but no I don't not have experience with nominatim. You're supposed to show us what you have tried. You need to make an effort to solve the question yourself before you come on here asking for help.

Comment: Also, you're confusing a comment with an answer.  I was not attempting to answer the question, I was attempting to get you to add more details to your question so that it could be answered by someone else with experience with nominatim.  If you choose to be rude and hurl insults you should not be on this forum.  Take your ill will somewhere else.  This site is about collaboration and any effort to help is not a waste of time.